# can't modify layout defined in layout.xml at runtime (nullPointerException)

Tags: android

I can't add a sub-layout to the main layout of my activity at runtime. More precisely i get a null pointer exception when i call **setContentView(layout)** or **layout.add(mySubLayout)**, where layout is retrieved by **findViewById(R.id.idLay)**. Below here there is the xml code.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/idLay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".TrainingActy" >
```

Seems that is not possible modify layout created statically. But i see answers on stack overflow that seems possible doing what i want, and i've never read in the documentation of android nothing about the impossibility of do it.

Comment: post the code and stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to modify a layout at runtime regardless of how it was created. Here's an example of how to do it. I assume in this example that layout you posted is in file `main.xml`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ViewGroup main = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.idLay);
    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setText("This is a test!");
    main.addView(text);
}
```

This, of course, won't modify your resource file, so when you inflate it next time, you'll have to run it through all the steps again.

Answer (score 1):

Resources Cannot be modified at runtime. But you can use an inflater to get the layout view and then add views to that layout.

Answer (score 0):

findViewById(id) returns a View, whereas Layouts are a Viewgroup.

I would suggest to write another XML with your layout. Then you include it as you described:

```
mainLayout.add(R.layout.your_custom_layout);
```